# Obtain the number of rows update with a JDBC Request in JMeter

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

I am using Jmeter in order to perform an update on a table. It is working fine in the sense it is updating the rows but I am not able to find out how to get acknowledge of how many rows were updated.

As an example I'm using this query:

```
Update MIG_LOT set STATE='LIBRE' where LOT=2033
```

On the JDBC Request I used *UPDATED* on the field *Result variable name* but it doesn't seem to put in it the number of rows updated or any other information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it was easier.

Just attach a Regular expression extractor:

[image: Jmeter Capture]

Using in *Reference name* the name I want for the variable, `([0-9]+) updates`as the *Regular Expression*, $1$ on the *Template* and 1 as the *Match number*.

And I can access the number of updated rows through the *UPDATESREGEXP* variable.